# Understanding electronic loads

Tags: operational-amplifier

I found an article about electronic loads and tried to simulate the circuit in LTSpice. However it didn't work.

[Here](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-54529/l/how-does-an-electronic-load-regulate-it-s-input-voltage-current-and-resistance) is the link to the full article, where I tried to recreate the following figure:

[image]

Do you agree that this circuit is wrong and not working!? I'd argue that we have to use an integrator (PI controller) instead of the lone operation amplifier.

Comment: Please modify your question to show your circuit as simulated, and describe how it did not work.  In theory an op-amp would work there, and AFAIK in practice there are some op-amps designed to drive capacitive loads that would work there.  Most op-amps would require some form of compensation in the feedback because of their non-zero output impedance among other things.  This feedback would not be of a sort that I would call a "PI controller".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the conceptual circuit. It's a simple 1A current sink. If you simulate this with practically any op-amp and a MOSFET such as a 2N7000 it will work fine at relatively low currents (from uA up to say 100mA)

In actual practice at the 1A level it **might** not be stable without compensation for the MOSFET gate capacitance loading, but that is highly dependent on the op-amp characteristics and on the MOSFET characteristics (in particular Cgs). [Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa808/snoa808.pdf) is an op-amp designed to be stable with very heavy capacitive loads, but it's not hard to accomplish with ordinary op-amps by closing the loop for higher frequencies separately from the gate DC. The gate then charges through an isolation resistor but that's not really PI control, as Tim says.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLQH7O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I still think that without the feedback loop, the circuit wouldn't work, because if the sensed voltage matches the reference voltage the op-amp will output 0V and turn of the mosfet!? This can be solved by adding a capacitor to the feedback loop as shown by @spehro, which gives the circuit an integrating transfer function.

Comment: If the feedback voltage is slightly less than the 1V reference the op-amp output will drive the MOSFET on. That only takes a few uV of error, which is less than the op-amp offset voltage typically. You can think of this as a P controller with very high gain, or take the op-amp (usually a dominant pole at maybe 10Hz) internal compensation into account, which is sort-of a PI or I.

Comment: DC open-loop gain of an op-amp is typically in the hundreds of thousands or millions.